# Portable Key-Value data file format for Hadoop?

Tags: c++, python, hadoop, portability, key-value

I'm looking for a portable Key-Value data file format that can serve as an input and output format for Hadoop and is also readable and writable apart from Hadoop directly in C++, Java, and Python.  One catch... I need to have support for processing with non-java mappers and reducers (specifically c++ via Hadoop Pipes).

Any ideas?  Should I write my own portable Key-Value file format that interoperates with Hadoop and Hadoop Pipes?  Would such a new format be useful to the community?

**Long Version:**
Hadoop Sequence files (and their cousins Map, Set, Array, and BloomMap) seem to be the standard for efficient binary key-value data storage when working with Hadoop.  One downside of Sequence Files is that they are readable and writable only in Java (they are specified in terms of serialized java objects).  I would like to build a complex multi-stage MapReduce pipeline where the input and output to various stages must be readable and writable from  C++, java, and python.  Furthermore, I need to be able to write mappers and reducers in a language other than java (i.e. c++) in order to use large and highly optimized c++ libraries in the mapping stage.

I've considered various workarounds, but none of them seem... attractive.

1. **Convert** : Add extra conversion stage before and after each MapReduce stage to convert the stage's input and outputs between Sequence Files and a portable format compatible with other languages.

   - Problem: The data consumed and generated between stages is quite large (TB)... It is expensive to duplicate the data multiple times at each stage just to get read / write access in a different programming language.  There are 10 stages, this is too much overhead for me to pay for ($$$).
2. **Avro File** : Use Avro's portable data file format.

   - Problem: While there does seem to be code to allow the portable Avro data file to serve as an input or output format in a MapReduce, it only works with mappers and reducers written in Java.  I've seen several discussions about creating support for mappers in other languages via the avro/mapred/tether package, but only java is currently supported.  From the docs: "Currently only a Java framework has been implemented, for test purposes, so this feature is not yet useful."
     http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.5.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/tether/package-summary.html
3. **Avro File + SWIG** : Use Avro data format with a Java mapper that calls a custom SWIG wrapped c++ library accessed from the distributed cache to do the real processing.

   - The immutability of java strings makes writing SWIG wrappers a pain and inefficient because a copy is required.  Also, this many layers of wrapping is starting to become a maintenance and debugging and configuration nightmare!

I am considering writing my own language portable Key-Value file format based on the H-File format that interoperates with Hadoop and Hadoop Pipes... Are there better off-the-shelf alternatives?  Would such a portable format be useful to the community?

Comment: @thomas-jungblut: I also stumbled over this and did a quick edit (Avero -> Avro)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a couple of miss-assumptions:

> One downside of Sequence Files is that they are readable and writable only in Java (they are specified in terms of serialized java objects)

Depends on what you mean by serialized java objects. Hadoop uses the WritableSerialization class to provide the mechanism for serialization, not the default Java serialization mechanism. You can configure hadoop to use default Java serialization (`JavaSerialization`), or any custom implementation of your choice (through the `io.serializations` configuration property).

So if you use the Hadoop Writable mechanism, you just need to write a reader for C++ that can interpret sequence files, and then write c++/python equivalents of the classes you wish to serialize (but this would be a pain to maintain, and leads to your second question, Avro)

> Furthermore, I need to be able to write mappers and reducers in a language other than java (i.e. c++) in order to use large and highly optimized c++ libraries in the mapping stage

You can write mappers / reducers in python / c++ / whatever currently using Hadoop Streaming, and use Sequence Files to store the intermediate formats. All streaming requires is your mapper / reducer / combiner expects  the input on stdin in `key\tvalue` pairs (you can customize the delimiter instead of tab), and outputs in a similar format (that again is customizable).

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html (I'm sure you've found this link, but just in case).

So what if you want to pass more complex key / value pairs to / from your streaming mapper / reducer - in this case i would say look into customizing the contrib/streaming source code, specifically the PipeMapper, PipeReducer and PipeMapRed classes. You could, for example amend the output/inputs to be `<Type-int/str,Length-int,Value-byte[]>` tuples, and then amend your python / c++ code to interpret appropriately.

With these modifications, you could use Avro to manage the code around serialization between  the hadoop streaming framework (Java) and your c++/python code. You might even be able to use the Avro.

Finally - have you looked into the `AvroAsTextInputFormat` and `AvroTextOutputFormat` classes, they may be exactly what you are looking for (caveat, i've never used them)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  

**Serialization**

Comment: **Java Only Format**
When I claimed Sequence Files are a "java only" format, I am not referring to the serialization of key-value pairs (which is configurable as you mention), but the low-level format of bytes written to disk that determine the container format itself.  The format is specified in terms of serialized java primitives (e.g. java's internal representation of a variable length integer, etc).  This makes it difficult to write a parser in other languages. Do you know of a working C++ implementation of a reader / writer for sequence files?

Comment: I found someone who tried to implement a parser for the sequence file format in pure python.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work correctly because it doesn't handle parsing some values of variable length integers:
https://github.com/matteobertozzi/Hadoop/tree/master/python-hadoop
This would be a great proof-of-concept for creating a non-java sequence file parser library in another language (e.g. c++)... Unfortunately, I wasn't able to debug the issue with parsing the java primitive types...

Comment: **Why I Find Hadoop Streaming Lacking**
1. I am processing binary data not text, so there is no natural delimiter character or fixed sized format that I can use to split keys and values from stdin.
2. Hadoop Streaming only offers a limited part of the MapReduce API (no partition, combiner without java)
3. The use of stdin stderr for data transfer conflicts with other uses of these streams by thirdparty libraries (for example, to print status info to the console)
4. Several benchmark shows hadoop streaming has a high overhead compared to regular hadoop: http://epcc.sjtu.edu.cn/dmw/racs2011.pdf